# How to distinguish two lists with the same elements in Python?

Tags: python

Say we got two lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

All the following expressions will return True:

```
a == b  # True
a == list(b) # True
a == list(tuple(b)) # True
a == copy.deepcopy(b) # still True
```

Here `a` and `b` are 2 different list objects with the same elements. 
How do we distinguish one from another?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do that requires this behaviour?

Comment: @detly It's a little complex, but i will try to explain.  I've got a data generator that outputs list object(the Contianer) which contains other lists ( the Elements). the Container is child of some other container. The two Containers generated may be a same container with different Elements, and may be two different one with the same Elements. And I need to do calculation with different Elements in a same Container. Is there any better way to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is` compares identity. It asks are `a` and `b` the same object

```
>>> a=[1, 2, 3]
>>> b=list(a)
>>> id(a)
3065460108L
>>> id(b)
3073003244L
>>> id(a) == id(b)   # Equivalent to a is b
False
>>> a is b
False
```

Comment: thanks! so id() is what python uses to distinguish different objects.

Answer (score 5):

Lists are compared (using `==`) element by element and the integers are compared with their values. Anyway, `a` and `b` are different objects and comparing them with `is` will return `False`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a is b
False
```

Comment: thank you! i think i should go over <learning python> again !

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]
print(id(a) == id(b))
```

Try this . id(objectName) gives address of object in memory and as they are two different object and so have different memory address.